# fit method in python sklearn

Tags: python, model, scikit-learn

I am asking myself various questions about the fit method in sklearn.

Question 1: when I do:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
model = TruncatedSVD()
svd_1 = model.fit(X1)
svd_2 = model.fit(X2)
```

Is the content of the variable model changing whatsoever during the process?

Question 2: when I do:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
model = TruncatedSVD()
svd_1 = model.fit(X1)
svd_2 = svd_1.fit(X2)
```

What is happening to svd_1? In other words, svd_1 has already been fitted and I fit it again, so what is happenning to its component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Question 1:** Is the content of the variable model changing whatsoever during the process?

Yes. The `fit` method modifies the object. And it returns a reference to the object. Thus, take care! In the first example all three variables `model`, `svd_1`, and `svd_2` actually refer to the same object.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
model = TruncatedSVD()
svd_1 = model.fit(X1)
svd_2 = model.fit(X2)
print(model is svd_1 is svd_2)  # prints True
```

**Question 2:** What is happening to svd_1?

`model` and `svd_1` refer to the same object, so there is absolutely no difference between the first and the second example.

**Final Remark:** 
What happens in both examples is that the result of `fit(X1)` is overwritten by `fit(X2)`, as pointed out in the [answer by David Maust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34731794/3005167). If you want to have two different models fitted to two different sets of data you need to do something like this:

```
svd_1 = TruncatedSVD().fit(X1)
svd_2 = TruncatedSVD().fit(X2)
```

Answer (score 5):

When you call `fit` on `TruncatedSVD`. It will replace the components with those built from the new matrix. Some estimators and transformers in scikit-learn like [IncrementalPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html) have a `partial_fit` which will incrementally build a model by adding additional data.