# Sklearn /scikit learn using fit method

Tags: python, scikit-learn

how does **fit() method** works in sklearn.preproessing using Imputer class
what does exactly fit() do in back ground how it is necessary for below code and 
everywhere im seeing fitting what fitting with what , why and how ?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
impt = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)
impt = impt.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = impt.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

Comment: This question is to broad vor stackoverflow, sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fit" method in scikit-learn do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704226/what-does-fit-method-in-scikit-learn-do)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to *'fit'* your pre-processing on your training data only (as you would your model). It will learn some state, for the imputer this might be the *mean* of your feature. Then when you transform on your test / validation data, you use the state (i.e. the *mean* in this case) to impute the new unseen data. Using this design, it makes it really easy to avoid data leaks. Consider if you had imputed on your entire dataset. The mean that you use for the imputation now uses some of the information from your supposedly unsees test data. This is a data leak, your data is no longer truly unseen. Scikit-learn uses the `fit` / `transform` pattern to easily mitigate this common pitfall in machine learning.

Furthermore, because ALL sklearn transformers and estimators use this `fit` API, you can chain them up in a pipeline making it possible to do all your pre-processing easily on each fold of a k-fold cross-validation, which otherwise would be a very fiddly, tricky thing to do without errors.

Answer (score 1):

`Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)`

The above line creates an Imputer object which will impute/replace the missing values which are denoted as NaN's with the mean value of the values.

`impt = impt.fit(X[:,1:3])`

So it needs some data from which it can calculate `mean` which can be replaced by the missing values. This is normally done by a method `fit` which will calculate the values needed, mean in this case. The `fit` takes in some data to calculate these values and it is normally called the `training` phase.

`impt.transform(X[:,1:3])`

Once the values are calculated they can be used on the new data presented to it. In this case, it will replace the missing data with the calculated (in `fit` method ) mean. This is done via a `transform` method.

Sometimes one might want to run `fit` and `transform` of the same data. In such cases instead of calling fit followed by transform we can use `fit_transform` method.

`X[:,1:3] = impt.fit_transform(X[:,1:3])`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the aim of "fit" in preprocessing stage is to compute the necessary values (like min and max of each variable). Then with this value scikit learn can then preprocess your data but it couldn't before. It is also useful because you can then re use your preprocessor object later.

You can also use `fit_transform` if you like to do these 2 steps in one.