# Not getting any output while trying to run the fit function of LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Below is my simple code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

x = np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=0)

print(model.fit(x, y))
```

---

The output I am getting is:

```
LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='liblinear')
```

I have tried this with other data and in PyCharm as well, same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "fit" method in scikit-learn do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704226/what-does-fit-method-in-scikit-learn-do)

Comment: This is very low level question OP can easily check the Sklearn documentation. Why you leave the answers?! adding `model.fit(x, y)`
`model.predict(x[:2, :])`
`model.score(x, y)` He needs to just google first!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the described behavior is the expected & nominal one, and there is not any issue or error to be rectified or debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit learn's models all work in a similar way. The `fit` method does not return anything, it only updates the model's parameters, i.e. it does the training. [You can see it in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

If you want to return predictions as an example, you need to use the `predict` method. Note that you should use the `predict` method after fitting the model of course (this is valid any other method that needs a fitted model in order to make sense). Note that the models usually also implement a `fit_predict`method that does both at the same time.

Your code could look like this:

```py
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', random_state=0)
model.fit(x, y) #does the learning
predictions = model.predict(x) #getting the predicted values on the training dataset
```

Comment: What do you mean by `model.predict(x)`  it returns back `array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) `which is `x`.

Comment: `model.predict(x)` returns predictions, let's call them `y_pred`. In you case, `ypred = y` which means that the models has a 100%  accuracy **on the training set**.