# NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

Am new to ML and trying to run a decision tree based model

I tried the below

```
X = df[['Quantity']]
y = df[['label']]
params = {'max_depth':[2,3,4], 'min_samples_split':[2,3,5,10]}
clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_dt, param_grid=params, scoring='f1')
clf.fit(X, y)
clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(clf.best_params_)
```

And got the warning mentioned here

```
FutureWarning: Pass criterion={'max_depth': 2, 'min_samples_split': 2} as keyword args. From version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
  warnings.warn(f"Pass {args_msg} as keyword args. From version "
```

Later, I tried running the below and got an error (but I already fit the model using `.fit()`)

```
from sklearn import tree
tree.plot_tree(clf_dt, filled=True, feature_names = list(X.columns), class_names=['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica'])

NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 
'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Can help me with this on how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go with `best_params_`, you'll have to refit the model with those parameters. Note that these should be unpacked when passed to the model:

```py
clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(**clf.best_params_)
clf_dt.fit(X, y)
```

However, you can also use the `best_estimator_` attribute in order to access the best model directly:

```py
clf_dt = clf.best_estimator_
```

Comment: thanks upvoted. But I got this error `
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'tree_'`

Comment: but I already imported tree from sklearn

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to access `clf.tree_`?

Comment: thanks, it worked now. I made a mistake by referring incorrect `clf` instead of `clf_dt`

Answer (score 1):

So there are two problems you are facing.

#### Firstly

Referring to

> FutureWarning: Pass criterion={'max_depth': 2, 'min_samples_split': 2} as keyword args. From version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an error

You might try using `dict` class constructor when creating `params`:

```
params = dict(max_depth=[2,3,4], min_samples_split=[2,3,5,10])
```

But this warning seems weird and it didn't occur for me.

#### Secondly

Referring to

> NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704226/what-does-the-fit-method-in-scikit-learn-do) you can learn about the **mandatory fitting step in sklearn**. But as you said, you just did so in your first code example. Your problem is that using

```
clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(clf.best_params_)
```

You instatiate a new `DecisionTreeClassifier` class which is therefore not fitted when you call

```
tree.plot_tree(clf_dt ...)
```

When you call

```
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_dt, param_grid=params, scoring='f1')
```

sklearn automatically assigns the best estimator to `clf` in your case. So just use this variable :)
The following step `clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(clf.best_params_)` isn't necessary.

Comment: `params = dict(max_depth=[2,3,4], min_samples_split=[2,3,5,10])` is exactly what the OP used and `clf = GridSearchCV(clf_dt, param_grid=**params, scoring='f1')` is invalid syntax.

Comment: You're right with the invalid syntax thing. My mistake. Using the alternative for creating the param dict was just a suggestion. I don't really understand why this warning occurs.